# Content Security Policy : Facing inline style issue in node package

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, content-security-policy

I am implementing CSP(Content security policy) in React js project So CSP is blocking inline style of one of node package . if any component face this issue then I can easily move inline style into external css file but now how can we fix inline style issue for node package.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of inline styles, the elimination of each of them requires its own approach.

1. The `<style>` tag. This kind os inline styles can be fixed using by some packages which automatically add `'hash-value'` of such styles into `style-src` directive. For instance [`react-static-plugin-csp-meta-tags`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-static-plugin-csp-meta-tags) or [`csp-html-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csp-html-webpack-plugin).
2. The `<tag style='...'>`inline styles. If some module inserts such style at the client side, you can only refactor code of this module or do not use it.
   If this kind of inline script been send from the server side, you can catch server rendered code before sending it to browser and replace `<tag style='...'>` to the `<tag data-style='...'>`. Then `data-style` attribute can be parsed ot the client side and element styles can be set by a CSP-safe calls `element.style = 'style_prop'`.
3. An `element.setAttribute('style', 'set_of_props')` javascript calls is considered as inline styles too. In this case, you can use a not very beautiful solution with substitution of `setAttribute('style', 'set_of_props')` function by a set of separate calls `element.style = 'style_prop'` from a 'set_of_props'.

In any case, it is impossible to deal with the abstract problem of inline styles, more specifics are needed (package causing a problem, the kind of inline style which has been blocked, SPA or SSR  app, ...).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand correctly, but if you are trying to fix some code coming from npm packages (`node_modules` folder) this is basically impossible.

You have two options:

- You can fix it on the package repository with a pull request and wait for it to be accepted or not and deployed in a further release of this module.
- Or you can fork this module and use a personal copy of the current version where you fix the issue.

But if you want to allow inline CSS while using CSP you can do it as explained here: https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-style/

Comment: If I want to allow inline CSS only for this node_package.I don't want to allow for whole project. Can I achieve this to minimise inline CSS security risk ?

Comment: No, if you want your package to work, you only have the two options I detailed. Node modules are packaged by your bundler to one code regardless of it being your code or vendor code. So no way to differentiate it